# Using array reduce to reduce two properties of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to store all duplicates and unique values of suits and values of an array of Card objects. Each card has a `suit` and `value` property. The datastructure looks like this:

```
cards = [
    {
        suit: 'spades',
        value : 4
    },
    {
        suit: 'hearts',
        value : 4
    },
    {
        suit: 'spades',
        value : 11
    },
    {
        suit: 'spades',
        value : 12
    }
    etc...
]
```

I'm trying to use `array.reduce` to check and store duplicates and unique values and suits for both, but am having trouble structuring the code.

Rules:

- 3-of-a-kind with different suits
- 4-card-run (with incrementing values) with same suits

Basically... I need to check each card's value and suits... and count the duplicates and uniques of values and suits. I'm struggling passing in an array of objects and using reduce on it.

Output: something like

```
melds : { 
      values: [4, 4, 4]
      suits: [spades, hearts, diamonds]
},
runs : {
      values: [11, 12, 13],
      suits: ['spades', 'spades', 'spades']
}
```

Code:

```
        function calculate(cards) {
            var my_array = cards.reduce(function(prev_array, curr, index, array){

                if (prev_array.duplicates.values.indexOf(curr) !== -1  || array.lastIndexOf(curr) !== index) {
                    prev_array.duplicates.values.push(curr);
                } else {
                    prev_array.uniques.values.push(curr);
                }

                if (prev_array.duplicates.suits.indexOf(curr) !== -1  || array.lastIndexOf(curr) !== index) {
                    prev_array.uniques.suits.push(curr);
                } else {
                    prev_array.duplicates.suits.push(curr); 
                }

                return prev_array;
            }, 
                {
                    duplicates : {
                        values : [],
                        suits : []
                    },
                    uniques : {
                        values : [],
                        suits : []
                    }
                }
            );

            return my_array;
        }
```

---

Edit:

```
var values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6];
var suits = ['spades', 'spades', 'spades', 'spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'hearts'];

var test_values = potentialRunsAndMelds(values);
var test_suits = potentialRunsAndMelds(suits);

        function potentialRunsAndMelds(array) {
            var my_array = array.reduce(function(prev_array, curr, index, array){

                if (prev_array.duplicates.indexOf(curr) !== -1  || array.lastIndexOf(curr) !== index) {
                    prev_array.duplicates.push(curr);
                } else {
                    prev_array.uniques.push(curr);
                }
                return prev_array;
            }, 
                {
                    uniques : [],
                    duplicates : []
                }
            );

            return my_array;
        }

var values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6];
var suits = ['spades', 'hearts', 'spades', 'spades', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'spades'];
```

---

EDIT 2:

```
            var runs = Object.keys(groups.suits).map(function (suit) {
                var values = groups.suits[suit].sort();
                var run = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    if (values[i+1] - values[i] === 1) {
                        if (run.indexOf(values[i+1]) === -1) {
                            run.push(values[i+1]);
                        }
                        if (run.indexOf(values[i]) === -1) {
                            run.push(values[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (run.length >= 4) return run;
            });
```

Returns : `[Array[4], undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Where `Array[4]` is `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

How can I not return `undefined`?

I suppose I can just do:

```
            runs = runs.filter(function (run) {
                return run.length;
            });
```

Comment: Is there some reason all of this *must* happen inside a single array.reduce loop? It might be easier to find runs by (1) grouping cards by suit, (2) sorting by value within the suit, and (3) iterating over each suit looking for runs.

Comment: I was doing them separately before. The issue was I would verify the duplicates and uniques needed for `3-of-a-kind w/ different suits` and `4-card-run with same suits` but the card ended up being decoupled from their suits and values. So if you satisfied having `3 of a kind` in the array and `3 different suits`, it would return `true` for a meld even though the suit might not match to the correct value. See above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be trying to do too much in one reduce function; maybe try breaking this into steps? Anyway, having your reducer group by value and suit would simplify things.

```
var groups = cards.reduce(function (accumulator, card) {
  // Group by value.
  accumulator.values[card.value] = accumulator.values[card.value] || [];
  accumulator.values[card.value].push(card.suit);

  // Group by suit.
  accumulator.suits[card.suit] = accumulator.suits[card.suit] || [];
  accumulator.suits[card.suit].push(card.value);
  return accumulator;
}, {values: {}, suits: {}});
```

Once you've done that, it's much easier to find melds and runs.

```
// Melds
var meldValues = Object.keys(groups.values).filter(function (value) {
    // Check for duplicates in this array, if so inclined.
    return groups.values[value].length >= 3;
});

// Runs
var runs = Object.keys(groups.suits).map(function (suit) {
    var values = groups.suits[suit].sort();
    // (1) iterate over values
    // (2) append each value to current 'run' as long as it's consecutive
    // (3) if not consecutive, start a new run. if duplicate, discard.
    // (4) return all runs with length >= 4
});
```

Comment: Don, this is pretty cool! In the `reduce`, you need to return `accumulator` btw. So, what is `accumulator.values[card.value] || [];` doing?

Comment: Don please see `EDIT 2` above. I'm returning consecutive values that discard duplicates. It's returning the expected array I need, but also returns `undefined`. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Oops, thanks for the fix on the reduce function. The `|| []` bit is just making sure there's an empty array started for that key - otherwise you'd get undefined errors on the next line.

Comment: @Growler Your `EDIT 2` code looks really close. You can do a `filter()` after your `map()` as you mention, or else do a single `reduce()` for that step. In that case your accumulator would be an array, and you only push to the accumulator if the run is >= 4. There's no way to filter within a `map()` function.

Comment: Thanks Don. I ended up just chaining the filter to map: `Object.keys(groups.suits).map(function (suit) { ... return run; }).filter(function (run) { return run.length });`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't gamble and maybe I quite don't understood what you want to achieve, but it seem to me, that you forgot to get property value from `cards` array.

You are passing the `curr`

```
if (prev_array.duplicates.values.indexOf(curr) !== -1 ...
```

But `curr` is card object.

```
cards = [
{
    suit: 'spades',
    value : 4
},
```

You should target `suit` and `value` like `curr.suit` and `cur.value`.

And because in JS, Objects cannot be easily compared so `lastIndexOf(object) === indexOf(object)` equals in all cases. and you need to check `uniques` Array if the value is'nt already there, because you cannot rely on `lastIndexOf()`.

Also, because Objects cannot be easily compared, testing duplicity with Object is bad idea.